# A way to check if iOS app exists in App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm working on episodic game for iOS and would like to have a menu with links to all the episodes. When the menu is shown, I want to check if the episodes are available in App Store or not, and depending on the answer enable a button to take the user to the game's App Store page.

Is there any way of checking the existence of an app in the App Store?

All the questions I found were about checking if the user had INSTALLED certain other app on their device, but all I want to know is if it exists in App Store.

I already tried [canOpenURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL%3a) but that returned true for any App Store url such as http://appstore.com/nononondsds
(Docs say "It does not guarantee that the full URL is valid.")

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using in app purchase for delivering the episodes rather than separate apps. You may find (though no guarantee) that Apple are not to keen on separate apps for each episode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apple API as follows:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Skype
```

Where "term" would be the search criteria. This will give you a JSON encoded result.

For full documentation you can check [Apple Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html)
Hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Or you just need to your App's appstore URL to https://fnd.io/ and if it returns correct response mean your app is there on appstore

Answer (score 0):

OK, first thing I'd do is listen to @AdamRichardson. It might be a better idea to release each episode as an in app purchase rather than a new app?

However, if you want to do your AppStore thing then I'd do it by having a server with data on it that you can inspect.

On the server have an API that returns a list of your Apps that are available on the app store.

This way you don't need to go to the app store to check you can just update your server.